# php - how to flatten a nested array via array_map?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this:

```
<?php

$blocks = [
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "content" => "foo",
    ],
    [
        "id" => 2,
        "content" => "bar",
    ],
    [
        [
            "id" => 3,
            "content" => "foo",
        ],
        [
            "id" => 4,
            "content" => "qux",
        ],
    ],
    [
        "id" => 5,
        "content" => "waldo",
    ],
    [
        "id" => 6,
        "content" => "foo",
    ],
];

$out = array_map(function ($block) {
    return $block["content"];
}, $blocks);

print_r($out);
```

which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => 
    [3] => waldo
    [4] => foo
)
```

(and an undefined index error)

How do I adjust it to flatten the nested items? Duplicates must remain, and the relative order must be retained, producing:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => foo
    [3] => qux
    [4] => waldo
    [5] => foo
)
```

Comment: Any specific reason with array_map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be work fine.

```
    <?php

   $blocks = [
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "content" => "foo",
    ],
    [
        "id" => 2,
        "content" => "bar",
    ],
    [
        [
            "id" => 3,
            "content" => "foo",
        ],
        [
            "id" => 4,
            "content" => "qux",
        ],
    ],
    [
        "id" => 5,
        "content" => "waldo",
    ],
    [
        "id" => 6,
        "content" => "foo",
    ],
];

   
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($blocks));

foreach($iterator as $key=>$value)
{
    if($key === "content") {
        $newArray[] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($newArray);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can archive it by using `array_walk_recursive` and `unset`

```
array_walk_recursive($blocks, static function ($item, $key) use (&$result) {$result[$key][] = $item;});
unset($result['id']);
```

---

In `array_walk_recursive($blocks, static function.....` it will produce array-like

[image]

with `unset($result['id']);` output is

[image]

---

or even shorter

```
array_walk_recursive($blocks, static function ($item, $key) use (&$result) {
    if ($key === 'content') {
        $result[] = $item;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Wintermute What's wrong with this? Less code + explained too?